# Nativescript IOS Push Notifications only work in development

Tags: android, ios, angular, firebase, nativescript

I have built an Android and IOS app using Nativescript and Angular. Part of the app requires the use of push notifications, and for this I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Having followed the documentation for Firebase, I created an APN development/distribution certificate and uploaded them to my firebase app. Within the first screen on the IOS/Android app I execute the following code

```
firebase.getCurrentPushToken().then((token: string) => {
   console.log("HELLO token!", token);
      if (token !== null && token !== undefined) {
         this.dataService.updatePushToken(token)
         .then(result => console.log(result))
         .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
      console.log("Push token: " + token);
});
```

This works fine in development for both platforms, however I only receive the push token in production for Android, and not IOS.

Is it likely that this is a certification issue or something wrong with the app itself? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?